# How to create a dropdown in RMarkdown html for an image and data.frame

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I have the following data.frame and image from online:

```
myTable <- data.frame(Test = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                      Test2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))

url1 <- "https://static1.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/rickroll-header.jpg?q=50&fit=contain&w=1140&h=&dpr=1.5"

url2 <- "https://people.com/thmb/JGjxumyykHNuBoeyuELz33P2uHY=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():focal(719x309:721x311)/rick-astley-recreation-never-gonna-give-you-up-081922-1-909d277568c34a599c27fa7503ce7a4c.jpg"
```

I'd like a way to create a dropdown when I knit an html file where the user can click on the title and the image and dataframe would drop down. I have found the following that utilizes the `bsplus` package which I am quite interested in

```
library(bsplus)
library(htmltools)
bs_accordion_sidebar(id = "myId") %>%
  bs_append(title = "Title1", content_side ="Statistics", content_main = htmltools::img(src = url1)) %>%
  bs_append(title = "Title2", content_side ="Statistics, content_main = htmltools::img(src = url2))
```

The output formatting is almost exactly what I want, however if I try to use `myTable` in the content_side parameter it only wants a vector, and only the first image of Sir Rick persists when I click on the other dropdown.  [image]

My dream would be to have an output very similar to the photo above, but to have the dataframe appear when clicking the title instead of the word "Statistics" and for the image to refresh to the new image depending on which title I click. I am open to other formats, more html/css, etc but I would like to keep this look & feel. Id also be open to an idea where the data.frame AND image are on the right-hand side arranged either side-by-side or on top of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render your table in the sidebar you have to create an HTML table of your data frame which could then be passed to the `content_siderbar` argument. To this end I use `knitr::kable(myTable, format = "html")` and wrapped in `htmltools::HTML()`.

Second, to make `bs_accordion_sidebar` work you have to add `use_bs_accordion_sidebar()` to the markdown (or Shiny UI).

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2023-10-14"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
myTable <- data.frame(Test = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                      Test2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))

url1 <- "https://static1.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/rickroll-header.jpg?q=50&fit=contain&w=1140&h=&dpr=1.5"

url2 <- "https://people.com/thmb/JGjxumyykHNuBoeyuELz33P2uHY=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():focal(719x309:721x311)/rick-astley-recreation-never-gonna-give-you-up-081922-1-909d277568c34a599c27fa7503ce7a4c.jpg"
```

```{r}
library(bsplus)
library(htmltools)
```

```{r}
bs_accordion_sidebar(id = "myId") %>%
  bs_append(
    title = "Title1",
    content_side = HTML(
      knitr::kable(myTable, format = "html")
    ),
    content_main = htmltools::img(src = url1)
  ) %>%
  bs_append(
    title = "Title2",
    content_side = HTML(
      knitr::kable(myTable, format = "html")
    ),
    content_main = htmltools::img(src = url2)
  )
```

```{r}
use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
```
````

[image]

And of course could you display both the image and the table as main content by wrapping in `htmltools::tagList`, e.g.

```
bs_accordion_sidebar(id = "myId") %>%
  bs_append(
    title = "Title1",
    content_side = HTML(
      knitr::kable(myTable, format = "html")
    ),
    content_main = htmltools::img(src = url1)
  ) %>%
  bs_append(
    title = "Title2",
    content_side = "Statistics",
    content_main = tagList(
      htmltools::img(src = url2),
      HTML(knitr::kable(myTable, format = "html"))
    )
  )
```

[image]